# Autofs: I'm able to mount one folder but not the other

Tags: nfs, autofs

I'd like to use autofs to mount two directories from my laptop to my lan-server. The problem is, that autofs mounts one directory but not the other...

This is how my laptop exports the directories:

**/etc/exports**

```
/home           192.168.178.10(ro,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,root_squash)
/home/peter      192.168.178.10(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,root_squash)
/media/peter/vm             192.168.178.10(ro,sync,fsid=1,no_subtree_check,root_squash)
/media/peter/vm/Windows_7_x64      192.168.178.10(ro,sync,no_subtree_check,root_squash)
```

The server shows me the exports like expected:

```
$ showmount -e peter-laptop

Export list for peter-laptop:
/media/peter/vm/Windows_7_x64 192.168.178.10
/media/peter/vm               192.168.178.10
/home/peter                   192.168.178.10
/home                         192.168.178.10
```

I can mount the NFS shares manually and it works fine:

```
 $ sudo mount peter-laptop:/home /home/peter/test_home/
 $ sudo mount peter-laptop:/media/peter/vm /home/peter/test_vm/
```

Now I unmount everything and try to mount again with **autofs**:

On the server I have this in **/etc/autofs.master** :

```
/import/peter-laptop/peter     /etc/auto.peter-laptop --ghost
```

And this in **/etc/autofs.peter-laptop** :

```
home -fstype=nfs4,ro,retry=0,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,tcp 192.168.178.20:/peter
vm -fstype=nfs4,ro,retry=0,rsize=12288,wsize=12288,tcp 192.168.178.20:/media/peter/vm
```

If I restart autofs I get one dir for each mount:

```
/imports/peter-laptop/peter/home
/imports/peter-laptop/peter/vm
```

Everything works fine for the home dir, but if I `cd` into `vm` I get this error:

```
$ cd vm/
-bash: cd: vm/: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I could do?

Comment: I would note that you seem to be doing 4 times the necessary amount of work here, assuming you only want to mount `/home` and all of it's subdirectories.

Comment: I want to mount `/home/peter` and `/media/peter/vm/Windows_7_x64` and subdirs of both.